# ad-hoc配布でアプリ起動時、すぐに落ちてしまいます。

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

はじめまして。

完全に八方塞がりとなってしまいました…。
ipaファイルの作成後、UDIDを登録しているデバイスでitunes経由でインストール。

そこまでは順調だったのですが、
インストールしたアプリを起動しようとすると即座に落ちてしまいます。

通常の実機シミュレートでは問題なく起動し、
証明書関連も入れ直してみたものの全く駄目です…。

経験がおありの方などいらっしゃいましたら知恵をお貸しください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます…。

外れるや切れるといった事はありませんでした。
UDIDについてもコピぺした内容ですので間違いはないと思われます。
証明書関連全ては再度作り直してみたので問題はありませんでした。
iPhone専用ですので問題はないかと思いましたがUniversalに変更してみても、駄目でした…。

アプリ自体は難しくもないアプリですので問題はない、と思いたいですね…。今までリリースの経験などは何度かあり問題無くこなしていましたが、クライアントに向けての仕事で納品前のこういった経験ははじめてなのでとてもパニクっています。

Comment: 「実機シミュレートでは起動できる」と書いてありましたね…あと考えられるとしたらiTunesのバージョンが古いとか、ipaの渡し方でセキュリティソフトが変に弄ってしまったとか、対象にするiOSが古いか何かで対象OSバージョンが違うとかですかね？

Comment: 端末に許可を求める動作は何かありますか？（カメラ・GPS・ネットワークなど)物理的にカメラが付いていない端末だったり、オフラインだったりして落ちてたりしませんかね？

Answer (score 1):

確認済みの事項もあるかと思いますが念のため

・開発グループのライセンスが切れた。
・証明書が削除された
・証明書の有効期限が切れた
・証明書を作成した開発者が開発グループから外れた
・アプリのIDが無効になった（削除されるなど)
・UDIDを登録した後に作成されたprovisioningファイルじゃない
・UDIDが登録されていない
・provisioningファイル作成時に有効にすべき端末にチェックが入っていない(Xcodeから自動生成だとコレは無いかなぁ……)

など思いつく限りかいてみました。

---

追記

単純にアプリ起動時に「メモリ確保できない」とか「ライブラリ読み込めない」とか
「ビルドしたアプリの対象が「iPhone」または「iPad」になっていて「Universal」じゃないとか
ビルドしたアプリ自体が悪い可能性もあるかも……

Answer (score 0):

Xcode の 「Window → Devices」から、実機デバイスの「View Device Logs」で落ちた時のクラッシュログが出てれば何かしらヒントになるかも知れないので確認してみてください。